# How to bind states and functions in different components without Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Main page, it has the `findUser()` and `inputValue` values, I want to make a static application header, but it has an `input that` requires `findUser()` and `inputValue` to use it, how can I pass them correctly (this can be done without Redux ?)

Main page:

```
const githubPageref = useRef(1);
  const reposRef = useRef([]);
  const [userNickName, setUserNickName] = useState('');
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState('');
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setinputValue] = useState('');
  const [reposCount, setReposCount] = useState(0);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [currentRepos, setCurrentRepos] = useState([]);
  const pageSize = 4;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const findUser = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setUserNickName(inputValue);
    const reposUrl = `${usersUrl + inputValue}/repos?page=${githubPageref.current}`;
    const profileUrl = usersUrl + inputValue;
    await getApiResource(reposUrl)
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data) { navigate('UserNotFoundPage'); }
        setRepos([...data, ...repos]);
        reposRef.current = ([...repos, ...data]);
      });
    await getApiResource(profileUrl)
      .then((data) => {
        setUserProfile(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

App:

```
const App = ({ findUser, setinputValue }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header
        findUser={findUser}
        setinputValue={setinputValue}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
        <Route path="a" element={<StartSearchingPage />} />
        <Route path="UserNotFoundPage" element={<UserNotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Context API](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-for-beginners/) from React as an alternative to Redux. Or simply, you could define what is need in `MainPage.js` and `Header.js` in `App.js` and pass them down. As an example this way:

```
const App = ({ findUser, setinputValue }) => {
  const githubPageref = useRef(1);
  const reposRef = useRef([]);
  const [userNickName, setUserNickName] = useState('');
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState('');
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setinputValue] = useState('');
  const [reposCount, setReposCount] = useState(0);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [currentRepos, setCurrentRepos] = useState([]);
  const pageSize = 4;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const findUser = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setUserNickName(inputValue);
    const reposUrl = `${usersUrl + inputValue}/repos?page=${githubPageref.current}`;
    const profileUrl = usersUrl + inputValue;
    await getApiResource(reposUrl)
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data) { navigate('UserNotFoundPage'); }
        setRepos([...data, ...repos]);
        reposRef.current = ([...repos, ...data]);
      });
    await getApiResource(profileUrl)
      .then((data) => {
        setUserProfile(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Header
        findUser={findUser}
        setinputValue={setinputValue}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
        <Route path="a" element={<StartSearchingPage />} />
        <Route path="UserNotFoundPage" element={<UserNotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```